# Jython - Convert Java array with Java Strings to Python list with Python strings

Tags: java, python, arrays, jython, jython-2.5

I'm using some Oracle API with Jython2.5. Once of the methods returns:

```
array(java.lang.String)
```

I would like to convert this to a python list, with strings as the elements in the list. e.g.

```
['some', 'strings']
```

I'm not sure how to do this, or if there's a simple method in the java.lang or java.utils library I can use for the conversion.

EDIT: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10530_01/doc/epm.931/html_security_api/javadoc/com/hyperion/css/common/CSSGroupIF.html

method GetGroupLists()

Comment: `Once [sic] of the methods returns:` Which method? Got a link to the documentation?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10530_01/doc/epm.931/html_security_api/javadoc/com/hyperion/css/common/CSSGroupIF.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use "tolist" on an array to convert it to a list:

```
grouplist = GetGroupList().tolist()
```